# how to use "order by" and "where" same times

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can I add   `order by 'id' DESC`  to this code?

```
$querya = mysql_query("select * FROM  {$table_prefix}  where act='1' and status='0' LIMIT  $start_at,$entries_per_page" );
```

Comment: $querya = mysql_query("select * FROM {$table_prefix} where act='1' and status='0' order by 'id' DESC LIMIT $start_at,$entries_per_page" );

Comment: @KryDos it should be `ORDER BY id` or `ORDER BY \`id\`` not with single quotes.

Comment: @今草顿웃, single quotes working perfectly into phpmyadmin. This not working with single quotes into mysql_query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to simply to be the real question... Than answer is this, I think.

```
$querya = mysql_query("select * FROM {$table_prefix} where act='1' and status='0' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT $start_at,$entries_per_page" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this. Use `id` (Reverse Quotes)

```
$querya = mysql_query("select * FROM {$table_prefix} where act='1' and status='0' 
order by `id`
LIMIT $start_at,$entries_per_page" );
```

Comment: of all the answers posted here, this is the correct one since it uses backtick rather the single quote in a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$querya = mysql_query("select * FROM {$table_prefix} where act='1' and status='0' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT $start_at,$entries_per_page" );
```